# How to create an overlay of a full screen application

Tags: vb.net, optimization, overlay

So I'm trying to make an overlay for a full screen game. Firstly this isn't for hacking purposes, the game shows times as little clocks and I find this difficult to read, so when I press a key to activate something I want to be able to see how long ago I activated it etc.

I currently have this code to write the time to the screen:

```
 Private Shared Sub DrawOverlay(ByVal OverlayString As String)
    Dim Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("GAMECLIENT")
    Dim deviceContext As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Processes(0).MainWindowHandle)

    Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim myBrush As New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(deviceContext.ClipBounds, Color.Black, Color.SkyBlue, Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Horizontal)
    Dim drawFormat As New StringFormat()
    drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback

    deviceContext.DrawString(OverlayString, drawFont, myBrush, 100, 100, drawFormat)
End Sub
```

To be clear this code isn't mine. It's just what I've found from research. This works, however it's extremely slow. It actually makes the game free for about 5 seconds. I *think* the time consuming line is:

```
deviceContext.DrawString(OverlayString, drawFont, myBrush, 100, 100, drawFormat)
```

By process of playing around with other lines it seems to be almost defiantly this line. However I can't work out how to speed it up. I even published the application, just in case it was the debugger. No difference. However this doesn't work for full screen which isn't ideal, if anyone could explain why that would probably help me out.

On a related note if anyone has/knows of a DLL I can reference to do this quickly and more effectively (ESPECALLY FOR FULL SCREEN) that would be great!

So to sum up:
1) Why is that line so slow
2) How should I speed it up
3) Is there another way to do this that works with full screen.

Thanks!

Comment: take the unnecessary variable initialization out of the function, and make the shared instances themselves.

Comment: I've actually tried this. It makes almost no difference. Thanks for the idea though.